# Scroll Bar doesn't respond

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

my ScrollViewer doesn't work as it is supposed to. It is shown, but it does not scroll as intended.

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <DockPanel>
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <MenuItem Header="_File">
                    <MenuItem Header="_Open"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="_Close"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="_Save"/>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
            <StackPanel></StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtWords" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="18" TextWrapping="Wrap" BorderThickness="0"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="#FFF0F0F0">
        <TextBlock x:Name="WordCount" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" Text="hello" Foreground="#FFBB2B2B" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
<!--I have also set the visibility to auto. I have also put the textbox inside a scroll bar. The same issue still persists.-->
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I have included all of my code. The textbox WordCount is the element with the issue.

[image: Here is an image of my screen.]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your `ScrollViewer` tag?

Comment: I have already put the textbox inside a scroll viewer tag, and I still have the same issue. @Mandy8055

Comment: Please have a look at this site to get a glimpse of it. I think you are missing something in here:http://www.codearsenal.net/2012/08/wpf-scrollviewer-control-example.html#.WaWiQsgjFEY

Comment: There is no ScrollViewer tag in the provided xaml. Have u tried to resize the window (making it smaller) to check if the ScrollViewer appears ?

Answer (score 1):

If you specify a height for the `TextBlock` you should see the built-in scrolling behavior kick in.

By default, a `StackPanel` will stretch to fit all of its children. Your `TextBlock` is stretching to fit all of its text, and its containing panel is stretching to accommodate the `TextBlock`.

Try setting either the `Height` or `MaxHeight` property to start to see scrolling.